# Slow inserts to CloudSQL via SQL Alchemy in Python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm experiencing a weird issue, where I'm posting roughly 5k records to localshost MySQL db, then to CloudSQL instance.
Localhost insert takes about 5 seconds, while CloudSQL takes ~5 minutes, and looks like my outbound traffic is about 12kbps (and I'm on a pretty fast internet).

I tried setting up the connection using both mysqldb, and mysql connector:

```
alchemy_connection = 'mysql+mysqldb://
alchemy_connection = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://
```

Neither one seems to improve the speed.

One thing to note - I'm connecting to the db via from a whitelisted IP, using server's assigned IP Address...

Second thing to note :) is that I am using sqlalchemy's bulkinsert statement.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I also just tried disabling logging + increasing instance size - that didn't do anything.

Comment: looks like for cloudsql - it takes ~20sec to post 1k records.
for localhost instance - it takes... trivial milliseconds to do the same.

Comment: utilizing cloud sql proxy to connect through did not make any difference either.  womp womp.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find a good solution to this issue, and a few other people seem to experience the same issue.

To circumvent slow inserts, I ended up splitting the list into a list of N lists.  Then launching N threads (at the same time, via threading+queue) to do the posting to CloudSQL.

This speeds up the posting speed by N, but with an extra a level of complication, and points of failure.

Best of luck everyone!